# How to replace this washing machine valve/faucet?

Tags: leak, faucet, washing-machine, valve

The valve leaks at the spot where the hose connects to the faucet. It has leaked with two different hoses. I'm trying to replace the valve, but it is not easy to get off. Is it designed to come off? Or do I need to hire a plumber to come in and cut the wall open and cut the pipe?

[image]

Comment: I don't "know" for fact, but I'll surmise there are threads where the body meets the lower piece.  In other words, use a wrench to hold that hexagonal "nut" stationary, and a second wrench, or maybe even open-end pliars, to grab the 'body' and turn it counter clockwise.   A real plumber probably has seen this before and knows exactly what's up, but I'm seeing an obvious seam between the body and that nut.  So it's not all one piece.  And it's probably not "glued" in place.    I woudn't go crazy trying to FORCE it to turn, but I bet it'll be easy to move with tools like I describe.

Comment: Before you do that though, are you sure your hoses have good washers???   You can replace the washers without replacing the entire hose. (Very cheap)   Is there any obvious deformations in the mating surface on the valve?  (It looks flat, but pictures can be deceiving).

Comment: Thanks! The washers look completely fine. One hose is only 6 months old and one hose is brand new. I hadn't checked the surface of the valve, but I did now and it seems to be in pretty good shape. I'll try taking it off how you suggested - I appreciate your help!

Comment: Sometimes you gotta tighten those hoses down with a pair of pliers.  Not super tight, but tighter than you can do by hand.

Comment: That outlet should have a smaller center hole to give a wider platform for the hose union washer.

Answer (score 2):

The threaded part on the valve where the hose connects seems, from the picture, to be rather short. It is possible that the part on the end of the hose is interfering with the valve body (represented by the green arrows in the diagram below) before the rubber hose washer gets a decent amount of compression on it.

[image]

If this is the case you may be able to purchase a thicker hose washer that is more supple than what is currently in the hose end to allow for the proper compression to seal the joint.

Also, as stated previously in the comments, it is often necessary to use a tool to turn the hose coupling tight to get a good seal.

Comment: You might try two washers in the hose coupling.

Comment: I am going to try to add another washer, or a thicker one. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Two hose washers can really be problematic as one can twist off the surface of the other leaving a huge leak psth